# Is it better to rely on an intention file or a database for a web chatbot?

Tags: training, chat-bots

Currently, I'm making a chatbot that is going to be functioning in a website, so I was wondering, is it better to train the chatbot with intentions files or use the database as the intention file, if it the latter, then how would I do it? With *SQLite* or with *Excel*? Any guides or tutorial would be appreciated.

I'm planning to use Flask + Python + Html for the chatbot.

Answer (score 1):

Recognising intents is only a small step in developing a chatbot. It's fine to use an ML classifier with training data for that, no need to keep the original list of intents.

However, you should really think about the next step: how are you getting your bot to conduct a dialogue, rather than firing off single responses to user queries. That is where things get difficult, and that is also what distinguishes a good chatbot from a simple-minded Eliza-clone.

The programming language/framework you use is not relevant.